# Parsing date and time from xlsx import

Tags: r, date

I have a column of dates with the following format in excel: MM/DD/YY AM or MM/DD/YY PM and was able to parse this date after importing with readxl::read_excel.

```
parse_date_time(x, '%m/%d/%y %p', tz = "UTC")
```

Now, if I wanted to bring in MM/DD/YY HH:MM PM instead, the import comes in as a number. For example.

```
"3/16/20 3:00 PM" becomes 43906.625 after import.
```

One solution would be to import date columns as strings, however, I have 50 columns in the file and don't want to hard code each column type. Is there a way to get the date and time from this numerical value instead (i.e. 43906.625)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel uses a "day-integer" format. R uses "seconds-integer" for time and "day-integer" for `Date`, so depending on which class you are converting to, you need to accommodate a day of seconds (86,400). It is also worth knowing that Excel uses an "origin" from 1899 (the year).

```r
as.POSIXct(43906.625 * 86400, origin = "1899-12-30", tz = "UTC")
# [1] "2020-03-16 15:00:00 UTC"
```

---

As a bit of history: the reason that it's `"1899-12-30"` and not, say `"1899-12-31"` (end of the day?) or something else is mentioned in a blog post from 2013:

> For Excel on Windows, the origin date is December 30, 1899 for dates after 1900. (Excel’s designer thought 1900 was a leap year, but it was not.) For Excel on Mac, the origin date is January 1, 1904.
>
> - https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/

I don't know the canonical reference for this, and the website from which R-Bloggers borrowed/scraped that article from is not responsive. I would much prefer to have still-active and more-canonical references for this assertion (that engineers mis-identified the leap-year).